# ajax call doesnt return the data from external JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement Repository pattern in JavaScript. I have ViewModel which i want to initialize with the data when i call Initialize method on it. Everything seems to be falling in places except that i am not able to return the data from my AJAX call. I can see that data is coming back from the ajax call but when i trying to capture the data in SomeViewModel's done function, it is null.

Can someone please point me out where i am going wrong here?

P.S: Please notice that i am not making Async call so the call chain is properly maintained.

This is how my Repository looks like:

```
function SomeRepository(){
    this.LoadSomeData = function loadData()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "someUrl",
            cache: true,
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            //success: handleHtml,
            success: function(data) {
                alert('data received');
                return data; 
            },

            error: ajaxFailed
        });



        function ajaxFailed(xmlRequest) {
                alert(xmlRequest.status + ' \n\r ' + 
                xmlRequest.statusText + '\n\r' + 
                xmlRequest.responseText);
        }

    }




};
```

This is how my ViewModel looks like:

```
function SomeViewModel(repository){   
    var self = this;
    var def = $.Deferred();

    this.initialize = function () {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    $.when(repository.LoadSomeData())
    .done(function (data) {
        def.resolve();
    });
    return def;
  };

}
```

This is how i am calling from an aspx page:

```
var viewModel = new SomeViewModel(new SomeRepository());
viewModel.initialize().done(alert('viewmodel initialized'));
alert(viewModel.someProperty);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used successfully an auxiliar variable to put the ajax result, when ajax call is inside a function (only works if ajax is async=false) and i need the function does return the ajax result. I don't know if this is the best solution.

```
function ajaxFunction(){
    var result='';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "someUrl",
        cache: true,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        //success: handleHtml,
        success: function(data) {
            alert('data received');
            result=data; 
        },

        error: ajaxFailed
    });
    return result;
 }
```

Comment: This does work, but synchronous ajax is really not a super good idea overall.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem is little different but you answer makes sense. I will accept it as that is one way to return data from ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter that it's synchronous (though it really shouldn't be).  Returning a value from inside the ajax callback will **not** cause the value to be returned from the containing function.

Using asynchronous ajax is generally a much better idea anyway, but that will force you to create an API that allows its clients to pass in handlers to be called when the ajax request completes. To do that, you'd give your "LoadSomeData" function a parameter.  A caller would pass in a function, and your ajax "success" handler would pass on the results (or some transformation of the results; depends on what it is that you're doing) to that callback.  It's the same idea as the callbacks used in the ajax call itself.

Comment: if thats the case, any suggestions on how to make it work so that UI loads the data?

Comment: Check the answer from @diegoe